# Placing the value of text of a selected tab in a global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, tabs

Am working on some custom tabs built using Jquery. When the user selects on a particular tab am capturing the text and storing it in a variable. This works fine but the issue is the variable should be in a global scope so that I can use it in another function (called execValue) outside the function that captures text from selected tab.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li class="columns">
        <label><span>Holiday/Business Trip</span></label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label><span>Winter Sports</span></label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label><span>Risky Sports</span></label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label><span>Study</span></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Logic**

```
let purpose = false;
let value = "";
$(".columns").click(function (value) {
    if (!purpose) {
        let reason = $(this).text();
        if(reason.trim() == "Holiday/Business Trip"){
            value = 'holiday';
        }
        if(reason.trim() == "Winter Sports"){
            value = 'Winter';
        }
        if(reason.trim() == "Risky Sports"){
            value = 'Risky';
        }
        if(reason.trim() == "Study"){
            value = 'study';
        }      
        console.log(value);
    }
});


function execValue(){
    //Capture value here
}
```

Comment: Just declare `value` outside the function?

Comment: declare the value outside your function with "var" or add it to the window object

Comment: @MuraliNepalli I have done that but still cant get the value in the next function..

Comment: @Martin: Did you add to the window object?...eg: window.value = "winter" ?

Comment: @MuraliNepalli Kindly explain with code sample or Jsfiddle ,, am a bit new to Js

Comment: @MuraliNepalli  Kindly check the updated answer am using

Comment: @Martin That seems fine. Now you can access "value" in execValue().  function execValue() { console.log(window.value)};

Comment: @MuraliNepalli Tried it but still not logging,, could you try from your  end on a Jsfiddle..

Comment: @CertainPerformance The context of the question is different,, its not duplicate

Comment: It looks like it, you're currently declaring `value` where it can't be seen by `execValue` - declare it outside instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Kindly explain using code sample,, am not understanding

Comment: @CertainPerformance Check updated answer,, still doesnt work

Comment: @Martin check this https://jsfiddle.net/zn9fy1p6/3/, open console and see the log statements

Comment: You have a `value` parameter, so `value` inside the callback refers to the parameter, not the outer variable. Best not to shadow variables

Comment: @CertainPerformance ,, Thank alot it finally works..

Comment: @MuraliNepalli Thanks alot for your help,, discovered the mistake I was making..